# Java concurrency try to lock

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

```
public class TestConcurrent{

 public static void main(String args[]){
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    boolean b1 = lock.tryLock();
    System.out.println(b1); //prints true       
    boolean b2 = lock.tryLock();
    System.out.println(b2); //prints true again
 }
}
```

The first try to lock manages to lock the object successfully.
About the second try, I would suppose that the second try to lock will return false since the object hasn't been unlocked yet. However it returns true again!!

Any explanation to this?

Comment: Read up on how locks work (in a single threaded scope).

Comment: Thanks. I just read the javadoc of the interface Lock, not the implementation class. Now it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from the [ReentrantLock.tryLock() Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock%28%29):

> If the current thread already holds this lock then the hold count is incremented by one and the method returns true.

If *another* thread tried to do the lock then it will return `false`.  But since it is the same thread that is locking again, it will return `true` and increment the hold count by one.  This means that you will have to `unlock()` it twice before other threads can get the `lock()`.

You can see this by looking at the hold-count:

```
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
assertEquals(0, lock.getHoldCount());
boolean b1 = lock.tryLock();
System.out.println(b1); //prints true       
assertEquals(1, lock.getHoldCount());
boolean b2 = lock.tryLock();
System.out.println(b2); //prints true again
assertEquals(2, lock.getHoldCount());
```

Answer (score 1):

- List item

This is only because you are aquiring the lock twice but from the same thread. This is the same as here

```
synchronized void x() {
    y();
}

synchronized void y() {
}
```

the thread will not block on y